# What should happen with edits like these?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I was looking at this question and checked the edit made on it.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57786064/revisions

The edit added some code in a code block, which was correct. It also added text in a codeblock, which was incorrect and then added the comment

> any help will be highly appericated!!

There is no need to add this and spelling *[appreciated](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/appreciated#Verb)* wrong is just careless.

Surely this edit shouldn't have been approved.

Should anything be done with the user and those that approved the edit?

Comment: That's not the only questionable edit of said user...

Comment: The edit comment is not very cromulent either.

Comment: I think a mod should hand out some edit and review suspensions.

Comment: @Floern are they able to suspend users from editing too?

Comment: @ChrisM: Yes, I think so. There is also an automatic edit suggestion ban when too many of the suggestions are rejected.

Comment: This is one of the more frustrating types. The type whose edits aren't completely harmful, but they're clearly misunderstanding edits and not even taking the task seriously. Wasn't there guidance to allow edits with even the slightest improvement through, removing anything that wasn't an improvement? And to ignore incorrect or gibberish edit summaries if the changes themselves are *at least* somewhat there? Stuff like this is why I strongly disagree with such guidance.

Comment: I think some people are under a misapprehension that, as in school papers, they need to indent the first line of every paragraph. If they could, I truly believe they would try to double the line height to simulate double spaced lines...

Comment: I think the two who approved this need to be contacted about editing rules, as well as the person who made the edit. This should ***not*** be happening! I just raised a flag on the Q to alert mods about the situatio with these three...

Comment: @CindyMeister would rolling back some of the poor edits be worth doing?

Comment: Not at this point, since your edit supposedly improved the post (I didn't read it in detail, which is why "supposedly"). If you encounter something like this again, where others have also approved and people *have a history* of this kind of thing, use a flag for moderator attention on the question explaining your concerns.

Comment: But, yes, when you come across a "new" one (for you), you can roll back then do your own edits, if you want to go that way. More important, however, would be that such things don't get approved to begin with.

Comment: Another one where the user has added a comment with a spelling error. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23926432 One of the users have approved over a thousand edits and only rejected 9.

Comment: Diamond moderators and OP's can overrule an edit review, at least until further edits/rollbacks are made. I'd rather see the edit review overruled than rolled back.

Comment: Rather than pointing out people here (directly or indirectly), we can contact the reviewers and editors. We can refer them to the guidance. Alternatively, alert a moderator using a custom mod flag. As a rule of thumb, include 3 recent bad edits/reviews in a custom flag - help the moderators to quickly assess the situation.

Comment: @BoltClock: The user seems to continue with their way of [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57804984/revisions) (adding noise and providing invalid edit summaries). Hasn't any mod talked to them so far?

Comment: @honk I raised a custom mod flag on one of their latest approved edits.

Answer (score 19):

First of all, the edit summary is a reason the edit should have been rejected.

Secondly, the fact that the suggestor added a "plz hlep me, urgnt" to the post should have made the reviewers pay more attention to the edit. They should have realized at that point that this edit was **not** worth 2 reputation points, simply because it didn't fix all issues with the post.

In addition, the suggestor added text in a code block. That's the second wrong thing: their edit **added** to the post which should have made the reviewers automatically *reject* the edit.

Comment: Is a bad edit summary really a reason to reject a suggested edit? Certainly it's a red flag that should have made the reviewers take a closer look and reject it on its other flaws, but if the edit were otherwise good I would think that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery If the edit summary contains content that would get it flagged if it was a comment, the edit has to be rejected. There’s no other way to prevent it from getting into the edit history. Also, the editor was adding gibberish to get around the requirement for an edit summary and we shouldn’t reward cheating the system.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery  I thought it was a harsh comment saying reject because of the summary, but thinking about it if someone is too lazy to write out a summary then they aren't taking care on the edit, or if they don't know why they are making the edit then that is also harmful.

Comment: @BSMP A summary *isn't* required though, you can always just let it default to "added/removed X characters" which isn't any more useful. Obviously rude, etc. edit summaries need to be dealt with, but gibberish that nobody is going to see unless they look at the edit history isn't causing any harm.

Comment: *A summary isn't required though...* @JohnMontgomery It is when users are *suggesting* an edit because they're supposed to be explaining to reviewers why they made their changes. We don't have to because we have editing privileges but if you suggest an edit anonymously it will require a summary.

Comment: @BSMP "Talk to the hand, because that's where the ears are now after the transplant surgery following the fall out of putting expandafoam up the nose which somehow blew out the ears." you surely haven't read [random's edit summaries](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/64730/randoms-absurd-edit-summaries-meta-only#resultSets).