# Multiple incorrect reviews with approvals

Tags: support, review-audits

Strangely, I just received two edits to one of my answers. Both edits were approved by 1 user and rejected by 2 users.

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24049936 (no improvement)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24062680 (vandalism)

Receiving an edit on one of my answers is very rare (possibly under 1%). Receiving two incorrect edits on the same answer *with approvals* is... rarer. What's going on?

Comment: Sometimes people win the lottery too, even though it's very rare. It doesn't mean there's a pattern or something special going on :)

Comment: @ivarni I suppose this might just be a variant of the birthday problem rather than the discovery of a henious underground review ring. :P

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I kind of hate how you replaced the `l` variable name with `xs` on every answer, forcing your arbitrary convention on millions of people. Nobody is confusing `l` with `1` in a tiny code snippet like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477486/how-do-i-use-a-decimal-step-value-for-range/477513). Python is not Haskell. Nobody uses "`xs`" as a variable name in Python. `l` is obviously "list", `xs` being short for "a bunch of 'X's" is not obvious to anyone who doesn't already know Haskell.

Comment: I guess it's not as bad as the guy who replaced `l` with the non-sensical `t`

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy I think `xs` is an elegant choice for generic lists since one can then do `for x in xs`. For specific lists, we use plural/singular in the same way, e.g. `for name in names` or `for word in words`. One could also use `for item in items` for generic lists, though that gets wordy in a comprehension, and `item` doesn't convey any more information than `x` does. But `l` should not be used as a variable name, as [PEP-8 enforces](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid), as do Pylint and PEP-8 compliant linters.

Comment: Side note, I think the `xs` was already there in that link. I assume you meant [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/365102) one instead. Anecdotally, here's an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1751478/revisions) where I thought a `1` was an `l` while trying to rename the `l` variables!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coincidence and reviewers that aren't reviewing properly.

That's all there is to it. At least the edits weren't approved.

Comment: I am curious if it has occurred that three people has robo-"approved" an edit that should not be approved.

Comment: @KarelG You only need two people to approve an edit and it happens regularly that there are mistakes, for example look at the edits mentioned in [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389121/7443472)

Comment: whelp. That is not even a mistake. I do review the edits seriously by reading its changes instead of just quick glancing over the content.